# Problem installing packages on BeagleBone Black with ROS Hydro

Tags: robotic-arm, beaglebone, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm having trouble installing packages in ROS Hydro on BeagleBone Black with Ubuntu ARM 12.04.

For example, when I tried to install vision_visp package, I did:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-vision-visp
```

But I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-vision-visp
```

The same error seem to occur when I try installing other packages as well. There is no problem with the internet connection, since I can ping another computer, and also ssh from another computer into the Beaglebone. Could I have done something wrong during the Hydro or Ubuntu installation process?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173303/problem-installing-packages-on-beaglebone-black-with-ros-hydro/) by [Alvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18825/alvin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [Hydro ARM build status page](http://packages.namniart.com/hydro.html) the vision_visp package isn't built for ARM.

Sorry, but you'll have to build it yourself from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18825/alvin/) on 2014-06-11**:
Oh, I did not realize that. Thanks for the response.